# Convert quint64 to qstring and vice versa

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm working on implementing [SimpleCrypt](https://wiki.qt.io/Simple_encryption_with_SimpleCrypt) encryption in my application. For that, I need to pass a quint64 value as key. During encryption, I want to generate a random quint64 value, use it for encryption and then add it to a text file. During decryption, I want to read the text file, obtain the key value and use it for decryption.

My "quint64 to qstring" and "qstring to quint64" conversion and my text file reading/writing mechanism isn't working properly.
My generated text file has the this type of content (The extra character is on a newline, I don't know why it doesn't look like that while pasting here):

1658
é

Can anyone explain how to do this the correct way?

```
//generating random quint64 key
qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());
quint64 key = (quint64)qrand();

//storing key in text file
QString keyStr = QString::number(key);
QString keyFileName = "key.txt";
QFile file3(keyFileName);
if(!file3.open(QFile::WriteOnly|
               QFile::Text))
{
    return;
}
else{
    QTextStream stream(&file3);
    stream<<keyStr;
}
file3.close();

//Reading key value from text file (in a different function)
int key;
QString keyStr;
QString keyFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open key file");
QFile file5(keyFile);
if(!file5.open(QFile::ReadOnly|
              QFile::Text))
{
    QTextStream in(&file5);
    in >> keyStr;
}
file5.close();
key = keyStr.toULongLong();
```

Answer (score 2):

is pretty str. forward in qt:

```
//from quint to string
quint64 number{18446744073709551615};
QString k{""};
k = QString::number(number);
qDebug() << "k is now: " << k;

//from string to quint
quint64 numberBack{1};
QString kBack{"18446744073709551615"};
numberBack = static_cast<quint64>(kBack.toULongLong());
qDebug() << "kback  is now: " << numberBack;
```

---

the arbitrary number: **18446744073709551615** is actually the max value a quint64 can hold, you can check that doing:

```
std::numeric_limits<quint64>::max()
```